# Dreamfactory - Remote Web Service - Pass parameter into the post body

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, dreamfactory

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass additional parameter in a remote web service.

Try to call an external soap xml webservice and link it to a remote web service in the dreamfactory. Now I want to parse the password credentials in a specific section of the soap xml request and send it through the external service.

Is this possible in the dreamfactory?

I've also try so link the service as a soap service but the validation of the wsdl file is not working for this service. -_-

Many thanks!